# Using an iterator, how do I skip a number of values and then display the rest?

Tags: iterator, rust

Random access to the elements is not allowed.

```
let vec = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
let n = 3;
for v in vec.iter().rev().take(n) {
    println!("{}", v);
}
// this printed: 0, 9, 8
// need: 8, 9, 0
```

`for v in vec.iter().rev().skip(n).rev()` does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I think the code you wrote does what you're asking it to. 
You are reversing the vec with rev() and then you're taking the first 3 elements of the reversed vector (therefore 0, 9, 8)

To obtain the last 3 in non-reversed order you can `skip` to the end of the vector minus 3 elements, without reversing it:

```
let vec = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
let n = vec.len() - 3;
for v in vec.iter().skip(n) {
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

Comment: Assume that the vector of 1000 elements. You will need skip 997 elements, then display the remaining 3 elements. I want to skip 3 elements from end, then print 3 elements, total: 6 moves.

Comment: @vigu iterators do not allow you to produce the same element twice, so you cannot iterate backwards and then iterate forwards over the same items again.

Comment: @Shepmaster compiler optimizes skip the first 1000 elements?

Answer (score 2):

Neither `skip` nor `take` yield `DoubleEndIterator`, you have to either:

- `skip`, which is O(N) in the number of skipped items
- `collect` the result of `.rev().take()`, and then `rev` it, which is O(N) in the number of items to be printed, and requires allocating memory for them

The `skip` is obvious, so let me illustrate the collect:

```
let vec = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
let vec: Vec<_> = vec.iter().rev().take(3).collect();
for v in vec.iter().rev() {
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

Of course, the inefficiency is due to you shooting yourself in the foot by avoiding random access in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, I guess you want to iterate specifically through the elements of a `Vec` or slice. If that is the case, you could use range slicing, as shown below:

```
let vec = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
let n = vec.len() - 3;
for v in &vec[n..] {
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

The big advantage of this approach is that it doesn't require to skip through elements you are not interested in (which may have a big cost if not optimized away). It will just make a new slice and then iterate through it. In other words, you have the guarantee that it will be fast.